# Symfony: reload only a partial

Tags: list, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel, partial

I'm working on a Symfony project and i need to implement a list in a partial (i use sfPropelPager for the pagination).

The problem is in the links to other pages, i must define a route in each of them `'module/action`, that means that all the page will reload. Its a problem because the list is in the middle of a form and some info may be lost when load the entire page.

So my question is: is there a way to reload only a partial (in my case the list) with new data on it and not the entire page?

If not, how would you solve this problem?

Thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use ajax have a look at jQuery $.ajax.

in your symfony action:

```
public function executeFoobar($request){
  if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) { // if the request comes form ajax
    return $this->renderPartial('foobar', array('foo' => $bar)); // returns the rendered partial
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm not familiarizated with ajax but i'll try to do it, thank you!

Comment: Try this sth like this `jQuery("#target").load(<?php url_for('module/foobar');` in your template !

Comment: Attention typo and missing quoting : `jQuery("#target").load("<?php echo url_for('module/foobar'); ?>");`